# Haskell Text Parser Combinators to parse a Range Greedily like Regex range notation

Tags: regex, parsing, haskell

In regex you can acquire a range of a parse by doing something like `\d{1,5}`, which parses a digit 1 to 5 times greedily. Or you do `\d{1,5}?` to make it lazy.

How would you do this in Haskell's Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP?

My attempt gave this:

```
rangeParse :: Read a => ReadP a -> [Int] -> ReadP [a]
rangeParse parse ranges = foldr1 (<++) $ fmap (\n -> count n $ parse) ranges
```

Which if you do it like `rangeParse (satisfy isDigit) ([5,4..1])` will perform a greedy parse of digits 1 to 5 times. While if you swap the number sequent to `[1..5]`, you get a lazy parse.

Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this with parser combinators?

Answer (score 1):

**update**: the below is wrong - for example
`rangeGreedy 2 4 a <* string "aab"`, the equivalent of regexp `a{2,4}aab`, doesn't match.  The questioner's solution gets this right.  I won't delete the answer just yet in case it keeps someone else from making the same mistake.

=========

This isn't a complete answer, just a possible way to write the greedy
version.  I haven't found a nice way to do the lazy version.

Define a left-biased version of `option` that returns Maybes:

```
greedyOption :: ReadP a -> ReadP (Maybe a)
greedyOption p = (Just <$> p) <++ pure Nothing
```

Then we can do up to n of something with a `replicateM` of them:

```
upToGreedy :: Int -> ReadP a -> ReadP [a]
upToGreedy n p = catMaybes <$> replicateM n (greedyOption p)
```

To allow a minimum count, do the mandatory part separately and append
it:

```
rangeGreedy :: Int -> Int -> ReadP a -> ReadP [a]
rangeGreedy lo hi p = (++) <$> count lo p <*> upToGreedy (hi - lo) p
```

The rest of my test code in case it's useful for anyone:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ go ["aaaaa", "aaaab", "aaabb", "aabbb", "abbbb", "bbbbb"]
   where
     go = print . map fst . readP_to_S test

test :: ReadP [String]
test = ((++) <$> rangeGreedy 2 4 a <*> many aOrB) <* eof
  where
    a = char 'a' *> pure "ay"
    aOrB = (char 'a' +++ char 'b') *> pure "ayorbee"
```